# How would i get the value between two integers in LUA

Tags: lua

Hi everyone i am trying compare integers by getting the amount between them

Lets say that i for example have a base integer 
`local i = 100`
Then i have other integers that are for example 200 and 300.
I want to get the amount between `i` and the other to values two see which one is closest to the base integer.

Comment: Do you want to get a random value between two other values?

Comment: I want to get the difference between the integers so 100 and 300 would be 200

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the 'distance' between two integers, you can just compute the absolute difference:

```
local i = 100
local x = 200
print(math.abs(i - x))
print(math.abs(x - i))
```

The [`math.abs`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-math.abs) function gets rid of any negative numbers resulting from the subtraction.